# Apagar linha específica de um arquivo de texto

Tags: c, arquivo

Preciso apagar a última linha de um arquivo de texto. Ele arquiva as coordenadas do usuário a cada linha, porém quando o usuário solicita um <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>, preciso apagar a última linha.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maneira usual de tratar ficheiros em C passa por fazer um ficheiro novo com o que se pretende do antigo.
Depois apagar o antigo (ou mudar-lhe o nome) e mudar o nome do novo para o nome original.

Qualquer coisa como

```
char linha[1000];
FILE *original, *alterado;
original = fopen("original", "r");
alterado = fopen("alterado", "w");
while (fgets(linha, sizeof linha, original)) {
    processalinha(linha);
    fprintf(alterado, "%s", linha);
}
fclose(alterado);
fclose(original);
unlink("original"); // ou rename("original", "original.bak");
rename("alterado", "original");
```

É claro que falta validação de erros no código acima!

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu meu problema

Comment: Diga-se de apssagem que essa solução não se aplica  só em C  - ao se tartar de arquivos texto, em qualquer linguagem, a única forma de criar alterações é escrever um arquivo novo. 

Por isso que quando o volume de dados aumenta (>100000 linhas por exemplo, ou dependendo da performance necessária bem antes disso) - a melhor coisa é colocar os dados numa base SQL, onde cada registro pode ser atualizado/removido de forma independente.