# Remover dados de um arquivo C++

Tags: c, arquivo

Estou fazendo um banco de dados para armazenar nomes de bandas de rock. Mas não estou conseguindo implementar a remoção de bandas separadamente. Alguém pode ajudar? Segue o código.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void banda(){
    ifstream arquivo("layout.txt");
    if(arquivo){
        string bandas;
    while(getline(arquivo,bandas)){
        cout<<bandas<<endl;
    }
    arquivo.close();
    }
    else{
        cout<<"erro";
    }
}

void inserir(){
    ofstream arquivo("bandass.txt", ios::app);
    if(arquivo){
        int a;
        string g;
        int b;
        string c;
        string nome;
        cout<<"nome da banda"<<endl;
        cin>>nome;
        arquivo<<nome<<endl;

        cout<<"genero"<<endl;
        cin>>g;
        arquivo<<"Genero: "<<g<<endl;

        cout<<"ano de criacao"<<endl;
        cin>>a;
        arquivo<<"Ano de criacao: "<<a<<endl;

        cout<<"ano de encerramento"<<endl;
        cin>>b;
        arquivo<<"Ano de enceramento: "<<b<<endl;

        cout<<"descriÃ§Ã£o"<<endl;
        cin>>c;
        arquivo<<"Descricao: "<<c<<endl;

    arquivo.close();
    }
    else{
        cout<<"erro";
    }
}

void remover(){
    ifstream arquivos("bandas.txt");
    ofstream arquivon("bandas.txt");
    string c;
    cout<<"Digite o nome da banda que deseja remover"<<endl;
    cin>>c;
    string aux;
    if(arquivos and arquivon){
        while (arquivos>>aux){
            if ( aux!= c ){
                arquivon<<aux;
                }
        }
    }
}
void buscar(){

    string a;
    cout<<"Digite o nome da banda desejada"<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    ifstream arquivo("bandass.txt");
    string aux;
    bool x=false;
    if(arquivo){
        while( arquivo>>aux){
            if( aux==a){
                cout<<"Essa banda encontra-se no arquivo"<<endl;
                x=true;
                }
            }
    arquivo.close();
    }
    if( x==false){
        cout<<"Banda nao encontrada no Arquivo."<<endl;
        cout<<"Tenha certeza que escreveu o nome corretamente"<<endl;
        }
}

void exibir(){
    ifstream arquivo("bandass.txt");
    if(arquivo){
        string bandas;
    while(getline(arquivo,bandas)){
        cout<<bandas<<endl;
    }
    arquivo.close();
    }
    else{
        cout<<"erro";
    }
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    bool n=false;
    char x;

    while( n==false){

        banda(); //cabeÃ§ario 

        cout<<"Inserir uma letra"<<endl;

        cin>>x; //opÃ§Ã£o escolhida

        if( x=='i' or x=='I'){
            inserir();

            char u;
            cout<<"Deseja retornar ao menu? Se nao, pressione a letra n, caso contrario letra s"<<endl;
            cin>>u;
            if( u=='n' or u=='N' ){
                n=true;
            }
        }
        else if( x=='r' or x=='R'){
            remover();
        }
        else if( x=='b' or x=='B'){
            buscar();
        }
        else if( x=='e' or x=='E'){
            exibir();
        }
        else if( x=='s' or x=='S'){
            n=true;
        }
        else{
            cout<<"Foi inserido uma letra nao existente no menu. Deseja continuar? Se nao, pressione a letra n, caso contrario aperte qualquer letra"<<endl;
            char y;
            cin>>y;
            if( y=='n' or y=='N'){
                n=true;
            }
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

---

Não dá erro, ele apenas não está removendo os dados do arquivo. No caso as bandas cadastradas

Comment: Qual o problema que o código apresenta ? Dá erro ? Se sim qual ?

Comment: Não dá erro, ele apenas não está removendo os dados do arquivo. No caso as bandas cadastradas

Comment: Eu não testei o seu código no entanto tenho pelo menos duas coisas a dizer. Você está sempre a mexer como tudo direto no arquivo, e isso regra geral não é boa ideia pelos mais variados motivos. Melhor é ler tudo para memoria, fazer todas as manipulações que pretende em memoria e quando é necessário grava para arquivo. Isto simplifica bastante em coisas como alterar 1 registo apenas. Outro ponto que tem errado no seu código é que na função `remover` você abre o mesmo arquivo para leitura e escrita simultaneamente. Isso é errado e não irá funcionar corretamente.

Answer (score 1):

Olá Rafael seja bem vindo.

Uma solução para o seu problema seria você copiar tudo em um novo arquivo .txt menos a linha/banda que você quer tirar, então deletar o .txt antigo e renomear o .txt novo para o nome do antigo.

Diga-se de passagem que essa solução não se aplica só em C/C++/C# - ao se tratar de arquivos texto/fichários em .txt, em qualquer linguagem, a única forma de criar alterações é escrever um arquivo novo.

Outra solução seria colocar os dados numa base SQL, onde cada registro pode ser atualizado/removido de forma independente.

Segue um exemplo de codigo para deletar algo de um txt:

[Eliminar linha de um arquivo em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/200234/)

[Apagar linha específica de um arquivo de texto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60095/)